# Delete [best-practice tag] or improve description - the status quo doesn't make much sense

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I came across the tag [best-practice](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practice) and in the description it says:

> (DO NOT USE: this tag has been applied very inconsistently, and probably should not be used.) Standard or recommended practices in writing, research, or professional academic conduct

So I wonder if the tag is often not used correctly and it even says it should not be used, why keep it at all?

My suggestion would be to either

1. Delete the tag altogether or
2. Improve the tag description and go through questions currently tagged with it and remove the tag from mistagged questions.
3. I am also open to convincing arguments why keeping a tag that people are explicitely told not to use does make sense and thus the status quo can and should be kept.

**Update:**
I have now removed the tag from all questions (and added some other useful tags where applicable). The tag should be deleted soonish. Not being a mod, I cannot mark this as "status completed", but it is.

Comment: I think it's clear that no one is an expert in "best practices" (and when would a question ask for the sub-optimal practice), deleting sounds fine.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- that would be fun, though. "looking for mediocre ways for teaching students", "I ve been accepted at a top tier conference, but that seems to much of a hassle - how can I switch to a lower tier venue?"

Comment: "I'm looking for a job that pays only a middling amount of money - is academia a good fit?"

Comment: Marked as `status-completed`. Thanks for the suggestion and the work!

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- - academia is an excellent place to look for middling pay!

Answer (score 5):

I think 1 is best provided it is done with mod-magic so that all those questions don't get promoted. Note that none of the current questions have only best-practice as a tag, though a few have only one other.

Comment: Though our powers run deep, this is not one of them. Deleting a tag means removing it from every question that has the tag; once they're all removed, the tag itself will disappear during a daily maintenance window. Nothing mods can do to make it more efficient or silent.

Comment: Oh rats. Maybe the OP here can take out a reference or two per day. We did this in cleaning up professorship a while ago.

Comment: It's just 29 questions, so it wouldn't take too long.

Comment: @Buffy I could start removing the tag little be little, trying not to upset the active questions too much. As Anyon said, there are not a lot of questions, so it will not take too long even if only a few are deleted per day.

Comment: I have now removed the tag from all questions (and added some other useful tags where applicable). The tag should be deleted soonish. Not being a mod, I cannot mark this as "status completed", but it is.